# What verb is implied at the end of this sentence: "it's too important not to"?

Tags: implication, elision

what verb is omitted after "to", in this sentence: "It's too important not to."

This is the full dialogue, for your reference:

> Believe me when I say that we will figure out this carbon project. **It's too important not to**. but it's going to be on my timeline, not yours.

Comment: What verb do you think it is? How many verbs come before it in the passage? Do any of them make sense?

Answer (score 2):

In the dialog, the person says that they will **figure out** this project. **Figure out** is the verb. It can be rewritten as:

> Believe me when I say that we will figure out this carbon project. It's too important not to figure it out, but it's going to be on my timeline, not yours.